# Symfony2's relation one-to-many

Tags: php, symfony

I have two tables. First table is stat_alert and second is user_qdf. i have a relation many to one between tables

I want to assign the value in the foreign key table
in my controller :

```
 $sql9="SELECT cell,id_user FROM stat_alert WHERE TYPE='C' AND id_user IS NULL LIMIT $purcent ";
  $h = mysql_query($sql9)OR DIE("Erreur sur la requeteee");

   $listes9 = array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($h)) {
     $listes9[] = $row;  
   }

   foreach ($listes9 as $liste9 )
   {
       $user_qdf = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AdminBlogBundle:UserQdf')
        ->find($cs);  
    echo $liste9[0];
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
       $alert = $em->getRepository('AdminBlogBundle:StatAlert')
                    ->findBy(array('cell' => $liste9[0]));
       **$alert->setUser($user_qdf);**

    $em->flush();
   }
```

i have this error Fatal error: Call to a member function setUser() on a non-object in D:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\alerteurs1\src\Admin\BlogBundle\Controller\GestionAlerteController.php on line 514

Comment: Why are you using plain MySQL in a symfony 2 app ??

Comment: I have not found how to do it with Symfony2 :(

Comment: You don't have a repository class for `stat_alert` ?

Comment: no I have class (entity) for stat_alert

Comment: then make a repository class for it, just as you did for UserQdf. What's more `$sql9` and `$liste9` are not good namings for variables... The number is totally useless, and you'd better write them in english not to have french/english mixed in your code.

Comment: And `$listes` and `$liste` aren't even good namings here : you'd better name them `$stats_alerts` and `$stat_alert` for instance. You code is very hard to read that way...

Answer (score 0):

`findBy()` returns a collection, not a object. Use `findOneBy()` instead and it should be ok.

Comment: thank you you can give me an idea how to fix this problem I'm stuck almost 2 hours; (

Comment: no, you didn't give enough context... the right question you should ask yourself here is : why do I have no rows with that 'cell' value ? Are you supposed to always have one ? If not, you just have to add `if ($alert)` before `$alert->setUser($user_qdf);`

Comment: if I write echo  $liste13[0]; i have TUN1409S1

Comment: And don't write `$liste9[0]`, write `$liste9['cell']`, it's much more understandable.

Comment: Anyway, after some time trying to understand your (quite dirty) code, it seems that the problem is that `findBy()` return a collection, not a object. Use `findOneBy()` instead and it should be ok.

Comment: I have already used   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
       $alert = $em->getRepository('AdminBlogBundle:StatAlert')->findBy(array('cell' => $liste13[0]));
           $alert->setUser($user_qdf);

             $em->persist($alert);
             $em->flush();